# How to pass Class of a type in swagger ApiOperation annotation response variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

In swagger I want to show the response which is a generic class. But it will not take the type of the class for the response.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get user name", response = ResponseWrapper.class)
// but I want to pass

@ApiOperation(value = "Get user name", response = ResponseWrapper<UserModel>.class)
// here I am getting error 
// how can I pass ResponseWrapper<UserModel>.class in the response variable

// In swagger response example body will be shown like :
/*
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "string",
      "message": "string"
    }
  ],
  "id": "string",
  "metadata": {},
  "response": {},
  "responsetime": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
  "version": "string"
}

But I want my response example body like this : 

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "string",
      "message": "string"
    }
  ],
  "id": "string",
  "metadata": {},
  "response": {
    "userName" : "string"
  },
  "responsetime": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
  "version": "string"
}
*/
```

The example code not having the ResponseWrapper of generic type but I want to pass Response wrapper of generic type.

Comment: What happens if you remove `response = ResponseWrapper.class`? I assume the annotated method is returning `ResponseWrapper<UserModel>` ?

Comment: In case the return type is wrapped once more in a generic there seems to be a way to unbox it: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/498#issuecomment-205718626

Comment: see I have several rest end points I made a common response object named ResponseWrapper<T> which take any type. If I remove the annotation it is working fine it will automatically detect and show the example response. But I have to do it in annotation.

Comment: In java there simply is no concept of typing a generic class during compile time. So `ResponseWrapper<UserModel>.class` cannot be represented without it's own class. You could build your own TypeResolver for Swagger that will wrap the `response = UserModel.class` in your generic `ResponseWrapper`. But I don't know how easy that will be

Comment: I know there is no way to resolve generic class using compile time. I will try the type resolver then will update the question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ok. I am curious about your result! Please post it as an answer in case you can solve it!

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this that I have found so far is to create an explicitly typed class implementing/extending your generic:

```
public class UserResponse extends ResponseWrapper<UserModel>{
}
```

This allows you to do

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get user name", response = UserResponse .class)
```

Comment: I do not want to use any extra class to set the response because for 1000 response I need to create 1000 classes

Comment: I feel your pain. Hopefully somebody else will have a solution

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the documentation. There is **no way** that we can pass generic "type" class  to the parameter of **@ApiOperation i.e. "response"**.

In my case I am returning **ResponseEntity** but with the help of advice I want I got the **ResponseEntity** and map it to the **ResponseWrapper** class.

But I need to show the user in Swagger UI that the response example is the 
**ResponseWrapper** object. So, I wanted to provide the ResponseWrapper class with its type in **@ApiOperation "response"** variable.

To do this I have to change the return type from **ResponseEntity** to 
**ResponseWrapper**. Otherwise there is no way. And type resolver will come into picture if your response is like **ResponseWrapper>**.

Comment: Adding clarity to the answer: Simply set it as the return type in the method and remove the response attribute from the @ApiResponse definition. For example:

    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful")})
    public ResponseWrapper<UserModel> getUser() {
    }

Swagger will generate the response example body with the attributes of user model as well.